# DBeaver suggest where keyword on insert into statement

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, dbeaver

I'm using latest DBeaver community edition on Oracle DB,

When creating  insert into statement

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA
```

The autocomplete suggest `WHERE` although there's no usage/meaning in [INSERT INTO syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm)

[image]

Also inside columns `INSERT INTO TABLEA (`

Why WHERE is suggested? is it DBeaver bug?

- also INTO isn't suggested after INSERT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Should be fixed in 22.0.2 milestone

Opened a [DBeaver issue](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/13879) which will be fixed on 21.3.0 milestone

> Remove where keyword suggession on Oracle insert into statement #13879